# R Name a list of dataframes in a list with a common word

Tags: r, dplyr

I have list of `dataframes` that I want to rename such that the word `Existing` appears in the name of each of the dataframe.

How can I do this without having to manually add the new name of each dataframe (my actual list has 10 dataframes)?

Sample Data list:

```
df_list= list(a=1:5, b=2:10, c=-5:5)
```

Desired output:

```
df_list = list(Existing, Existing_1, Existing_3) # Something similar
```

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

# Rename dfs in the list
names(df_list) = "Existing" #...stuck
```

Comment: do you need the names to be `Existing_1, Existing_2, Existing_3` etc?

Comment: @onyambu The names could be anything as long as they have the word `Existing` in them.

Comment: @onyambu just to add though if it makes any difference is that my actual list has 10 `tibbles` (`S3:tbl_df_/tbl/data.frame`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names(df_list) <- paste0('Existing_', seq_along(df_list))
df_list
$Existing_1
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$Existing_2
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$Existing_3
 [1] -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Use c(...) like this:

```
c(Existing = df_list)
```

giving:

```
$Existing.a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$Existing.b
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$Existing.c
 [1] -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5
```

**2)** If we remove the names first then we get this:

```
c(Existing_ = setNames(df_list, NULL))
```

giving:

```
$Existing_1
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$Existing_2
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$Existing_3
 [1] -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5
```